# make GNU gettext work for a MFC App

Tags: c++, mfc, internationalization, gettext

im trying to add i18n support with gettext on my mfc app, but i found the following problems

1) The ufficial distribution stopped to support MSVC, so i found another build here.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm

i fixed the include and linker path for the new libraries but when i try to use gettext it give me this error

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__libintl_gettext    ToolManager.obj ToolManager
```

Any idea of why? im pretty sure the important .lib are in the linker path.

Comment: Why not use Windows resources and LoadString()? There's MFC support for that. (I suspect they're GNU toolchain .libs not Microsoft toolchain .libs and that's why they won't link.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the binaries from ftp.gnome.org; latest gettext build is from 12-Sep-2010 and should AFAIK work fine with MSVC.

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/